# How to add time to a date in Sybase?

Tags: sybase

I'd like to take the current date in Sybase and set the time to 13:30:00.

Let say I do

```
select getdate()
12/5/2014 4:06:24.670 PM

I want to return
12/5/2014 13:30:00 PM
```

How do I transform that?

Answer (score 1):

I did not have time to test this but i would suggest you convert the date part of getdate() into mm/dd/YYYY and then add "13:30:00 PM" before you convert it back from a string into a datetime object.

```
select convert(datetime,convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)  + "13:30:00 PM")
```